# R code to open path associated with point on scatterplot

Tags: r

I have several scatterplots with many 1000's of 'test data' points, over which are plotted confidence ellipses to highlight clusters produced from a discriminant function analysis.  The datafame has x and y coordinates that are each associated with a Windows path to a sound file.  I need to manually check the raw sound data associated with selected points inside and outside these ellipses. When I open the dataframe in Excel, I can easily hyperlink each path and have the file open in my software of choice with one click. But, it would be quicker for me to interactively use a plot inside R - click on a point of interest, have Windows open the associated file.  So far I have failed at getting one of the interactive R packages or tools like ggobi to do this.  Would there be a one-click solution?  Thanks, and since I am a new R user, please be gentle.

Comment: `R` does have several ways to grab point coordinates, such as `identify`, `raster::click`, and `iplots` tools.  You might be able to write a function which grabs the coordinates returned from, e.g., `identify` and performs a "best-fit" lookup from a table of file names organized by coordinate values, and then call that file name.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response Carl and Paul.  Looks like Paul has provided a nice example which I understand - so I could click a bunch of points and end up with the selected_rows matrix.  In my dataframe, the last column would be a Windows path.  So I guess my next step will be to quickly send each of the anticipated many paths to Windows, where its file association will open it in the correct software.  Help with this would also be much appreciated.  My great thanks. user3157114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use standard graphics, you can have a look at the `identify` function:

```
plot(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)
selected_rows = with(mtcars, identify(wt, mpg))
selected_rows
[1]  3  4  8 26
mtcars[selected_rows,]
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had trouble with identify() with my own dataset in RStudio (crashed when stopped the identify() command), but it works fine in the RGUI.

Comment: I found the correct way to stop the `identify()` function in RStudio - a button in the plot window.