# Open files listed in txt

Tags: r, batch-file

I have a list of files with their full path in a single text file.  I would like to open them all at once in Windows.  The file extension will tell Windows what programme to use.   Can I do this straight from the command line or would I need to make a batch file?  Tips on how to write the batch file appreciated.

My text file looks like the following:

```
J:/630/630A/SZ299_2013-04-19_19_36_52_M01240.WAV
J:/630/630A/SZ299_2013-04-19_20_15_39_M02312.WAV
J:/630/630A/SZ299_2013-04-19_21_48_07_M04876.WAV
etc
```

The .WAV extension is associated with Adobe Audition, which is a sound editing programme.  When each path is hyperlinked in an Excel column, they can be opened with one click.  Clicking on the first link will open both Audition and the hyperlinked file in it.  Clicking another hyperlink will open the next file in the same instance of the programme. But this is too slow for hundreds of paths. If I open many files straight from R, e.g.

```
    shell("J:/630/630A/SZ299_2013-04-19_19_36_52_M01240.WAV", intern=TRUE)
    shell("J:/630/630A/SZ299_2013-04-19_20_15_39_M02312.WAV", intern=TRUE)
    etc
```

each file will be opened in a new instance of the programme, which is nasty.  So batch seems preferable.

Comment: Start with typing `help for` or `for /?` from a command prompt, and looking at the output for the `for /f` version. There's also an on-line version available at [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340(WS.10).aspx) that might be easier to read. `for` can be used from either a command ("DOS") prompt or a batch file. See the examples provided; they should give you a start. If you run into problems, you can use what you've tried to post a more specific question here. :-)

Comment: I am still stuck on this problem, if someone could help, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (yourtextflename) do "%%a"
```

should do this as a batch line.

You *could* run this directly from the prompt if you like, but you'd need to replace each `%%` with `%` to do so.

It's a lot easier to put the code into a batch:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%1) do "%%a"
```

then you'd just need to enter

```
thisbatchfilename yourtextfilename
```

and `yourtextfilename` will be substituted for `%1`. *MUSCH* easier to type - and that's what batch is all about - repetitive tasks.

Comment: Thanks Magoo.  I modified part of your batch file code to the following:`for /f "delims=" %%a in (%1) do start "%%a"`. when I call the batch file and the txt containing paths, the listed files will open in the DOS window rather than the programme the file extension should call in Windows. If I modify my list in the text to be like: `""C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Audition CS6\Adobe Audition CS6.exe"" ""J:/630/630A/SZ299_2013-04-19_19_36_52_M01240.WAV""` or with just one set of double quotes, I still cannot get it to work.  Sorry not been trained in computer languages, help appreciated.

Comment: The following modification opens the correct programme but not the files within it. `for /f "delims=" %%a in (test2.txt) do start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Audition CS6\Adobe Audition CS6.exe" "%%a"`

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample of your "single text file" showing a few representative lines.

Comment: Magoo gave you the answer here exactly. Leave off the `start` and call to Audition, and do **exactly** what was advised:  `do "%%a"`, where `%%a` would be `"J:/630/630A/SZ299_2013-04-19_19_36_52_M01240.WAV"`. Notice no call to `start`, no call to Audition - nothing but the line read from the text file.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I omitted to describe some earlier steps - I did try Magoos solution as described, then tried other stuff. Problem was Windows wants to open each path in a new instance of the programme assoc with filename extension. Situation the same for two other similar programmes when I change the file extension association. When I have the list of hyperlinked paths in an Excel column, the first clicked link opens the file in programme, second clicked link opens second file in same instance of programme - what I want.  Have accepted Magoo's answer and posted a new answer using R.

Comment: Apologies to Magoo - I found why his solution was not working in my hands. An instance of the software needs to be open (without or without other files already open inside) before I start the batch file. Then all files open in that one instance.  Such a simple thing I should have thought of.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904146/r-code-to-open-path-associated-with-point-on-scatterplot), which uses the `identify` function in `R` to create a subset selection of rows (from a larger dataset called "testfile") by clicking on coordinates in a scatterplot. One of the columns contains the list of Windows paths to original acoustic datafiles.  The last line below will open all files in the listed paths in only one instance of the programme linked to the Windows file extension.

`selected_rows = with(testfile, identify(xvalue, yvalue))`

`SEL <-testfile[selected_rows,]`

`for (f in 1:nrow(SEL)){system2("open",toString(SEL[f,]$path))}`